# Can you have hash tables in lisp?

Tags: data-structures, hash, dictionary, lisp

Can you have hash tables or dicts in Lisp? I mean the data structure that is a collection of pairs (key, value) where values can be acceded using keys.

Answer (score 14):

Common Lisp has at least four different ways to do that (-> key value storage):

- property lists   `(:foo 1 :bar 2)`
- assoc lists      `((:foo . 1) (:bar . 2))`
- hash tables
- CLOS objects     `(slot-value foo 'bar)` to get and `(setf (slot-value foo 'bar) 42)` to set. The slot name can be stored in a variable:  `(let ((name 'bar)) (slot-value foo name))` .

For simple usage assoc lists or property lists are fine. With a larger number of elements they tend to get 'slow'. Hash tables are 'faster' but have their own tradeoffs. CLOS objects are used like in many other object systems. The keys are the slot-names defined in a CLOS class. Though it is possible to program variants that can add and remove slots on access.

Answer (score 9):

Of course - Common Lisp has [hash tables](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node154.html).

```
(setq a (make-hash-table)) 
(setf (gethash 'color a) 'brown) 
(setf (gethash 'name a) 'fred) 
(gethash 'color a) => brown 
(gethash 'name a) => fred 
(gethash 'pointy a) => nil
```

Property lists are good for very small examples of demonstrative purpose, but for any real need their performance is abysmal, so use hash tables.

Answer (score 9):

If you're referring to Common Lisp, [hash tables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_h.htm#hash_table) are provided by a type called [`hash-table`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_hash_t.htm#hash-table).

[Using these tables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/18_a.htm) involves creating one with function [`make-hash-table`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_has.htm#make-hash-table), reading values with [`gethash`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_gethas.htm#gethash), setting them by using `gethash` as a [*place*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#place) in concert with [`setf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_setf_.htm#setf), and removing entries with [`remhash`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_remhas.htm#remhash).

The mapping from key value to hash code is available outside of hash tables with the function [`sxhash`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sxhash.htm).

Answer (score 5):

Clojure has a built-in map type:

```
user=> (def m {:foo "bar" :baz "bla"})
#'user/m
user=> (m :foo)
"bar"
```

See http://clojure.org/data_structures

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Here's the SRFI defining the standard hash table libraries in Scheme:

http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html

Answer (score 2):

There's built-in [hash tables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/18_.htm), that use a system hash function (typically SXHASH) and where you can have a couple of different equality checkers (EQ, EQL, EQUAL or EQUALP depending on what you consider to be "the same" key).

If the built-in hash tables are not good enough, there's also [a generic hash table](http://cdr.eurolisp.org/document/2/genhash.html) library. It will accept any pair of "hash generator"/"key comparator" and build you a hash table. However, it relies on having a good hash function to work well and that is not necessarily trivial to write.

Answer (score 1):

In Lisp it's usually called a property list.

Comment: No, property lists are something different.  See the CLHS glossary: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#property_list

Comment: Yes and no -- a property list isn't a hash table, but it does provide a dictionary-like interface (and his question specifies "...the data structure that is a collection of pairs (key, value) where values can be acceded using keys." A property list certainly provides exactly that, though without hashing (or anything approaching the same performance...)