# Lisp - Checking if a symbol is in a list of lists

Tags: list, if-statement, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to create a function which has a symbol/token and a list passed in

the function will then check to see if the list contains the symbol/token. if so return its corresponding key pair and if not return nul

I made a defparameter which was:

```
(defparameter *pairs* 
  '((apple green)
    (banana yellow)
    (grape purple)))
```

i then made a function to do the task:

```
(defun list-pairs (word list)
  (if (eq word list)
    (rest(list)))
  nil))
```

the function when executed as such : `(list-pairs '(banana) *pairs*)` i keep getting nul

what i want to be returned is yellow i.e. the key pair

can someone please help me as to explaining whats wrong. I am very new to LISP

Comment: Why not use the LISP hash mechanism, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837438/can-you-have-hash-tables-in-lisp/1837533#1837533

Comment: its because ive only just started learning lisp so im just trying to complete the task using fundamentals before using something a bit more advanced :) i.e just using defun, if statements, cons, first, rest zerop, numberp etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
(defun list-pairs (word list)
  (if list
    (if (eq (caar list) word)
      (cadar list)
      (list-pairs word (cdr list))))))
```

or, using let as a small optimisation:

```
(defun list-pairs (word list)
  (if list
    (let ((c (car list)))
      (if (eq (car c) word)
        (cadr c)
        (list-pairs word (cdr list))))))
```

which works well with a Common Lisp implementation that does tail-call optimisation; you should use it like

```
(list-pairs 'banana *pairs*)
```

but in Common Lisp the loop macro is generally preferred:

```
(defun list-pairs (word list)
  (loop for c in list
    when (eq (car c) word)
    return (cadr c)))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(second (assoc 'banana *pairs*))
```

gives

```
YELLOW
```

**Edit**: See Joshua Taylor's comment below for documentation about `assoc` and the concept of association lists (or short: *alists*) that it works with (very briefly: *alists* are a key-value data structure formed by lists of cons cells in which the `car` of each cons cell is the key and the `cdr` is the value).

About what's wrong with your own code:

In the condition of your `if`: `(eq word list)`, you are testing whether your argument `word` is the same as your argument `list`. But you actually want to look for `word` within `list`, so that cannot be the right condition.

Also, even if the condition were true, what you're then evaluating is `(rest(list))`. That is the rest of a new empty list, created by calling the function `list`, not the rest of your argument `list`.

And finally, you're closing the `if` expression after that `(rest(list))` with the third closing parenthesis there. Because of that, the final `nil` would be the return value of your function even if everything else would be correct. You need to move the `nil` into the parentheses of the `if` expression to make it the else-consequent, and the value of the `if` expression the return value of the function.

Comment: I'm glad to see `assoc` mentioned, especially as I think that it counts as one of the "Lisp fundamentals".  I wouldn't mind seeing a bit of discussion about what [association lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_aba.htm) are though, and what [`assoc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm) does…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Agreed, it would've been better if I had added an explanation of `assoc`. Thanks for providing the links to the CLHS, I will add a reference to your comment to my answer. (One reason I did not do so is exactly because I consider it a fundamental that every decent introduction into Lisp should've mentioned.)

Answer (score 1):

As another alternative:

```
(defun list-pairs (word list)
  (dolist (p list)
    (if (eq word (first p))
      (return (second p)))))

(defparameter *pairs* 
  '((apple green)
    (banana yellow)
    (grape purple)))

(list-pairs 'banana *pairs*)
YELLOW
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task leaves some questions open to me.

1.) Your function should get a symbol. But why do you call it like this: `(list-pairs '(banana) *pairs*)`? Wouldn't be `(list-pairs 'banana *pairs*)` sufficient?

2.) Do you only want to get matches for the first element of your pairs? I.e. Do you want the same result for the symbol `banana` and `yellow`?

If you only want to search for the first element, Rörd already mentioned `assoc`, which would be perfect.
If you want to check both elements of the pair, you can give `remove-if-not` a try.

```
(defun list-pairs (word list)
  (remove-if-not
   #'(lambda (sublist) (member word sublist))
   list))
```